# Gallery item width vs gallery width

Tags: android, gallery

I have a Gallery with a set of images that was downloaded at run time.

I followed the example here:
http://www.anddev.org/a_androidwidgetgallery_-_example-t332.html

but instead of using

```
i.setImageResource(this.myImageIds[position]);
```

I used

```
i.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(position));
```

This doesn't fill the entire width of the screen, only as much as the width specified here:

```
i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));
```

When I increase this number, the item scales with it instead of showing more images per the example. I've even tried to scale the images before adding them to the set. Not sure what I'm missing, or where other examples of this might be. Any help would be great, Thanks.

Comment: What is the goal - Gallery filling up the screen or item filling up the screen ?

Comment: I'd like the gallery to fill the width of the screen, and show more than just one image at a time.

Comment: How you want to fill the width and show more than one Image per time?

Comment: I want to show 4 images with each taking up 1/4 of the width of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can set the layout's width as the image's real size. or compute a scale factor by some logic. such as you can decrease the image's width when the image is far away the gallery center.

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(this.myContext);

```
        i.setImageResource(this.myImageIds[position]);
        /* Image should be scaled as width/height are set. */
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        /* Set the Width/Height of the ImageView. */
        int selectedPosition = ((Gallery) parent).getSelectedItemPosition();

        float scale = getScale(position - selected);

            int width = Math.round(IMAGE_WIDTH * scale);

            int height = Math.round(IMAGE_HEIGHT * scale);

            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(width, height));

        return i;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In your layout xml file be sure to set android:layout_width="fill_parent", like this

```
<Gallery 
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                        android:padding="1dip"
                        android:background="#AA000000"
            />
```